# Using local resources and building an Unity app

Tags: unity-game-engine

After building an Unity app, I can't `Instantiate` objects in my `Resources` folder. Here is an extract of the output_log.txt of this build:

```
ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null.
  at UnityEngine.Object.CheckNullArgument (System.Object arg, System.String message) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate (UnityEngine.Object original, UnityEngine.Transform parent, Boolean instantiateInWorldSpace) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[GameObject] (UnityEngine.GameObject original, UnityEngine.Transform parent, Boolean worldPositionStays) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

This error concern a prefab that can't be found by my script and concern those lines:

```
GameObject radio_button = Resources.Load<GameObject>(GlobalConfiguration.Instance.RootPrefabs+"/RadioButton"
foreach (string type in toggle_names)
{
   if (type == string.Empty || type == null) continue;
   GameObject go = Instantiate(radio_button, parent, false);
   (...)
```

`GlobalConfiguration` contains `RootPrefabs = "Prefabs";`.

This is a problem with prefabs but I also encountered with external resources such as JSON files. What am I missing ?

For info, I'm using VRTK.

Comment: Post screenshot that shows where you put the RadioButton item. Also select it and post screenshot of its Inspector tab

Comment: It is placed at runtime and how would that help if the prefab is null ? That's what I understand from the logs. It's working well while launching the app in Unity's editor.

Comment: Where exactly is the prefab and other objects stored? Are you sure your path is correct? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html

Comment: The prefab is stored (with all others prefabs) in `Assets/Resources/Prefabs`. So when I access it with `Ressources.Load<GameObject>('Prefabs/...')`. I don't get why this problem happens only on the built application.